# Why is a class defined within a function not usable after calling the function?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I wrote below code snippet:

```
def definer():
    class A:
        print("Inside class")

definer()
a = A()
```

and got following output on command line

```
Inside class
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "tuple.py", line 81, in <module>
    a = A()
NameError: name 'A' is not defined
```

Why is `A` not defined after running `definer()`?

Comment: Related reading: [Is it a bad idea to define a local class inside a function in python?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22497985/2745495)

Answer (score 2):

Most of the time, what happens within a function, stays in that function. In this case, you define a class that belongs to the function local namespace and it ceases to be after the function exists. If you want to use it outside, you need to return it (alternatively, you can try making it a global variable):

```
def definer():
    class A:
        def hello(self):
            return 'hello'
    return A

A = definer()
a = A()
print(a.hello())
```